# Result of method compilation

Tags: pharo, opal-compiler

When using

```
SomeClass compile: someSourceString
```

the symbol containing method's name is returned. Is there any reason why not an instance of `CompiledMethod` is returned? There are couple of tests like:

```
tutu compile: 'foo'.
self deny: (tutu >> #foo) allLiterals last key isNil.
```

Is there any method that returns a compiled method like:

```
compileMethod: aString
  ^ self >> (self compile: aString)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this ?

```
(SomeClass compiledMethodAt: (SomeClass compile:'foo'))
```

This will return the compiled method you need.

Comment: Yes, `>>` is a shortcut for `compiledMethodAt:`. The question is why would you return selector, and use something like `(SomeClass compiledMethodAt: (SomeClass compile:'foo'))` to get method when you can return a method and get selector with `(SomeClass compile:'foo') selector` if needed.